# illegai state exception in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have two pages newaccount.jsp and login.jsp.I have written two response.sendRedirect statements.but it is not working. giving exception illegal state.plz help me out.my code is here.Thanks for reply

```js
<%-- 
    Document   : insert
    Created on : Jun 6, 2017, 9:34:05 PM
    Author     : comp
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.*" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <form bgcolor="skyblue" >
    <body>
    
        <% 
           int flag=0;
            
          String mfname=request.getParameter("fname");
          
           String name=request.getParameter("mname");
            String mlname=request.getParameter("lname");
            String muname=request.getParameter("uname");
            String mpassword=request.getParameter("password"); String memail=request.getParameter("email");
              String mobno=request.getParameter("mobile");
          
            
         Connection con = null;

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
              con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gayatri","root","root");
//out.println("connection successfull");
            Statement stat = con.createStatement();
            Statement stat1 = con.createStatement();
String query1="select Uname from registration";

        String queryText = "insert into registration(Fname,Mname,Lname,Uname,Password,Email,Mobno) values('"+mfname+"','"+name+"','"+ mlname+"','"+muname+"','"+mpassword+"','"+memail+"','"+mobno+"')";
            ResultSet rs=stat1.executeQuery(query1);
while(rs.next())
{
    if(muname.equals(rs.getString("Uname")))
    {
    out.println("username exists");
   
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
   break;
    }
flag=1;
 }
 if(flag==1)
 {
int rst = stat.executeUpdate(queryText);
response.sendRedirect("newaccount.jsp");
 }
           
            stat.close();
            con.close();
       
   
            %>
    </form>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of illegal state exception? What's the message? On which line of the code is it triggered?

Comment: remove your if block validating flag ==1 and run the application

Answer (score 0):

IllegalStateException is thrown because `response.sendRedirect()` is called twice. You should call it only once. In addition, `stat` and `con` should be closed in finally block.

Comment: You should also change the positions of `<form bgcolor="skyblue" >` and `<body>`.